# How to get a list of defects in QC11.0 via C# OTA using BugFilter

Tags: c#, ota, hp-quality-center

I have successfully connected to QC using VBscript via the OTA interface. In VbScript I had the following code to filter out defects and get load them in a list.

```
BugFilter.Filter("BG_STATUS") = "Not Canceled and NOT Closed" 
BugFilter.Filter("BG_PROJECT") = "Business*"


Set BugList = BugFilter.NewList()
```

The above worked flawlessly in Vbscript.

In C#.NET (4.0), I am able to connect to QC successfully but when I try to apply the  filter , it give me a error..

```
TDConnection qcc = new TDConnection();
qcc.InitConnectionEx(sr);

qcc.ConnectProjectEx("XXXX", "------", "----", "-----");

            if (qcc.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("connected");
                BugFactory bf = (BugFactory)qcc.BugFactory;



                bf.Filter["BG_STATUS"] = "Not Canceled and NOT Closed";
                bf.Filter["BG_PROJECT"] = "Business*";

                List bugs = (List)bf.NewList(bf.Filter);
```

on the last line of code , it gives me the following error "Could not convert argument 0 for call to NewList."

I am relative new to C#, Can anybody help me here?

Comment: What are the details for the `NewList` call? What type does it take as a parameter and what is the return type?

Comment: it returns a list and takes a "string filter" as a parameter.List NewList(string Filter);

Comment: I think passing in (what looks like) an array of strings to the function `NewList` you are causing the exception. It says it takes a string. You may want to try a string and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Try `bg.Filter.text()`

You'd need to check the method, 'cause I do that in java. But there is a method by that name. How I normally do that is like this:

```
List bugs = (List)bg.NewList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually pass a string into the bug factory by using the .Text property of the Filter object rather than the filter object itself.

For example, I've had success with handling the filtering like this:

```
var tdFilter = (TDFilter)bf_filter;
tdFilter["BG_STATUS"] = "Not Canceled and NOT Closed";
tdFilter["BG_PROJECT"] = "Business*";
var bugs = bf.NewList(tdFilter.Text);
```